# Why does running `echo $0` in the bash REPL only return the name of the bash executable, but in zsh return the absolute path to the zsh executable?

Tags: bash, zsh

Why does running `echo $0` in the bash REPL only return the name of the bash executable, but in zsh return the absolute path to the zsh executable?

In bash:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ echo $0
-bash
```

In zsh:

```
in ~
  echo $0
/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get in `$0` depends on how the shell was invoked.  If you start it with `bash`, it'll be `bash`.  If you start it with `/bin/bash`, it'll be `/bin/bash`.  Ditto for `zsh`.

```
$ bash
$ echo $0
bash
$ exit
exit
$ /bin/bash
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
$ exit
exit
$ /bin/../bin/../bin/bash
$ echo $0
/bin/../bin/../bin/bash
$ exit
exit

$ zsh
$ echo $0
zsh
$ exit
$ /bin/zsh
$ echo $0
/bin/zsh
$ exit
$ /bin/../bin/../bin/zsh
$ echo $0
/bin/../bin/../bin/zsh
$ exit
```

Comment: Did you notice the dash character in '-bash' issued in bash shell that is just launched.  If you issue the bash command from that (to get a nested bash shell) then `echo $0` shows `bash` without that leading dash.  Why is that?  On macOS Sonoma with. zsh being the default shell, I get the same behaviour with zsh (`-zsh` inn the first zsh shell, then `zsh` in sub-shells started with the `zsh` command).

Comment: @PRouleau `-bash` (or whatever shell) indicates that it's a login shell.  From `man bash`: _A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option._